# How do I find search targets using Windows Explorer Search when I have python source code

Tags: python, full-text-search

I'm using Windows File Explorer to search for target words in programming language source code (I'm grading programs and I want to find matching phrases that suggest plagiarism - like misspelled comments or unique code... if I find the same word in 2 or more files, then plagiarism is suspected) I have 100 program source code files. I navigate to the folder where these files are located and I type a target word in the Windows Explorer Search field at the top of the page. If I am searching through .cpp file extensions, the search works as expected and supplies the files that have the target word. However, this process does not work if I search through 100 python files (that have .py extension). I get no matches with the python files even if I know the target word is in a python file... for example, searching for something common like "print"

I have verified that the Windows Explorer Indexing options include .py extensions (as well ad .cpp extensions - which works). If fact, I tried this experiment... I mixed .cpp files and .py files in the same folder, and I had 2 .cpp programs that referred to INT_MAX. Then I edited one of the python files and added "INT_MAX" to the python file. I ran the search and Windows Explorer found INT_MAX in the .cpp files, but did not find INT_MAX in the python file. So then I renamed the python file to have a .txt extension, ran the search again, and this time it found INT_MAX in the .txt file.

I've searched through Google and ChatGPT and followed the suggestions I found there. I still have the problem.

Thanks,
Rustee Gold

I googled the issue and was directed to Windows Explorer Indexing Options to make sure I had the .py extension selected. I asked ChatGPT and was given four detailed possibilities which I applied (also referring to the Indexing Options)

I still cannot search python files